# Reviving my asparagus fern

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, ferns

My plant has lost a lot of body recently as well as changing colour I think it is on its way out! Is there any way to revive?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can help your fern simply by misting it daily. That is the first step to try based off of the linked article. I recommend a stronger tactic for improving humidity: place it in your bathroom for a week or two and see if it perks up. If you don't have any windows in your bathroom, you could take it in as your shower pal. It will likely respond affectionately to this spa treatment and soak up the humidity and repay you by looking more like its old self.

[This article](https://www.thespruce.com/grow-asparagus-ferns-1902714) discusses how winter dryness can affect asparagus ferns, and depending on where you are in the world, this could be why you are seeing the change in your plant now- your heat recently kicked on and has removed much of the humidity your plant loved. The article recommends:

> Mist the plant daily, focusing on the arching stems. If the plant appears to be turning brown and droopy, it likely needs more water. While the asparagus fern can dry out to the point of appearing dead, it likely isn't. Warmer, humid air and daily misting will help revive it.